# Textures are shifted in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv

When I try rendering my model in Cycles, it warps the textures for whatever reason - here is an picture to demonstrate:

[image]

The windows should look the way they are on the right in the 3D view. What is be causing this?

Comment: I guess something in some mapping setting could be using wrong coordinates... difficult to say what exactly is wrong, without seeing settings or having a file...

Comment: You may want to upload the file. Also, do you have a subdivision surface modifier for example with a render value different to the view value? This may be causing your problems.

Comment: @m.ardito Good to mention *where* they can upload their file, e.g. here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ particularly as they are a new user.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have already unwrapped your model, so I am guessing that the problem is that Cycles isn't using the UV map you have created.

To tell Cycles explicitly to use a particular UV map add an *Input* > *UV Map* node and plug it into the *Vector* input on your image texture.  Make sure that the correct UV map is selected on the UV map node.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can check which UV map is being used as the default UV map under *Object Data* properties panel > *UV Maps* rollout.  You can set the default UV map by clicking on the small camera icon next to it.

[image]

This will only have an effect if there are no mapping coordinates explicitly defined for a texture as above.